# React Passing props to another looped Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to pass props of looped component(using array.map()) to other component, made as follows:

```
{this.posts.map((item, index) => {
    return (
         <Post
          item={item} 
          key = {index}
         />
    );
  })
}
```

So there are many 'Post' sibling components being rendered, but each with different items(data) and keys. Now I wish to send the props(to share a state between the two components) of one specific Post component to another specific sibling Post component. That is, I wish to select a specific Post component (maybe with the key value? and send a state only to another specific post component).
How would I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend binding a function that would update this.posts. That way your components will all update without having to take on potentially entangled states.

The idea is the function updatePosts will take a target index (key) child component to update and pass it the new state. In the code below, if you triggered updatePosts({firstName: 'Harry', lastName: 'Styles'}, 1), then the state would change from the first element being 'Foo Bar' to being 'Harry Styles', and the child components will rerender.

```
import React from 'react';

class PostMaster extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //the array you use to render child components will be managed in a state like this
      data: [
        {
          firstName: 'Foo',
          lastName: 'Bar'
        },
        {
          firstName: 'James',
          lastName: 'Bond'
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Harry',
          lastName: 'Potter'
        }
      ]
    };
    this.updatePosts = this.updatePosts.bind(this);
  };

  /**
   * stateData (object)     the data you want to go in a given index
   * index (int)            the child component you would like to update
  /
  updatePosts(stateData, index) {
    let newData = this.state.data;
    newData[index] = stateData;
    this.setState({data: newData});
    //you can always push instead of reassigning
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.data((item, index) => {
            return (
                <Post
                  item={item} 
                  key={index}
                  update={this.updatePosts}
                />
            );
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Im not sure if I have understood. So do I have to declare updateposts function in the post component I wish to send the data from?

Comment: I've edited the post, I hope it helps. But yes, you would declare the function to manage your React state. You'll send the data but you also need to provide it an index, since you want to be able to target which child component gets updated.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try and get back to you